# Argument of an arrow function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I'm new to React and would like to understand some of the following code:

**How does incrementValue receive the increment value? What is the link between the two? Where does incrementValue know to take the value of increment?**

Thank you.

Coded:

```
function App() {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const incrementCounter = (incrementValue) => setCounter(counter+incrementValue);
return (
<div>
  <Button onClickFunction={incrementCounter} increment={1} />
  <Button onClickFunction={incrementCounter} increment={5} />
  <Button onClickFunction={incrementCounter} increment={10} />
  <Button onClickFunction={incrementCounter} increment={100} />
  <Display message={counter}/>
</div>  
 );
 }
```

Comment: Check your Button component and the onClickFunction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I stronlgy recommend to get familiar with arrow-functions and reading the relevant docs - they are easy to understand after playing around with them a bit ;)

Comment: You are passing the function to the `Button` component. At some point that component will call the function with an argument. It's not magical. That's how functions work. If I have a function `function foo(bar) { console.log(bar); }` I can call it with `foo(42)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the Button component, onClickFunction prop will be called passing the increment value to it as an argument.

```
this.props.onClickFunction(incrementValue)
```

What happens is, incrementCounter function is passed to Button component, it can then be used through the onClickFunction prop

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer alone, if it can help anyone :

```
const {onClickFunction, increment } = props;
return (<button onclick={() => onClickFunction(increment)}></button>);
```